# Adding default file directory to FileDialog in Traits

Tags: python, file, enthought, traitsui

I am using the FileDialog class within TraitsUI, which works pretty well, except for the life of me, I have not been able to figure out how to pass a *default* directory, for the dialogue to use.

Ideally, the dialogue box would open at a point in the local file system other than the top of the tree...

Any insight or direction very gratefully appreciated from a newbie.

Base code pretty generic/standard as follows.

```
demo_id = 'traitsui.demo.standard_editors.file_dialog.file_info'

class FileDialog ( HasTraits ):

    # The name of the selected file:
    file_name = File
    # The button used to display the file dialog:
    open = Button( 'Open...' )

    #-- Traits View Definitions ------------------------------------------------

    view = View(
        HGroup(
            Item( 'open', show_label = False ),
            '_',
            Item( 'file_name', style = 'readonly', springy = True )
        ),
        width = 0.5
    )

    #-- Traits Event Handlers --------------------------------------------------

    def _open_changed ( self ):
        """ Handles the user clicking the 'Open...' button.
        """
        file_name = open_file( extensions = FileInfo(), id = demo_id )
        if file_name != '':
            self.file_name = file_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *not* using the TraitsUI FileDialog. I think you'll do better with pyface.api.FileDialog (toolkit-specific; for the API, see https://github.com/enthought/pyface/blob/master/pyface/i_file_dialog.py).

Comment: This is a more useful description of the API https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/wiki/FileDialogDemo

Answer (score 1):

this is an easy one. Basically, when you execute the `open_file` method, you have the opportunity to pass to it traits definitions which will in turn be passed to the `OpenFileDialog` object created within that convenience method. You are already doing so with the following

> open_file( extensions = FileInfo(), id = demo_id )

Simply add to that a definition for "file_name" and you're set.

> open_file( file_name="/foo/bar" extensions = FileInfo(), id = demo_id )

reading from the source of `traitui.file_dialog.py`, you can see the mechanism by which file_name gets passed from `open_file` to `OpenFileDialog`, the Handler responsible for representing the file dialog itself.

```
def open_file ( **traits ):
  ...
  fd = OpenFileDialog( **traits )
  ...

class OpenFileDialog ( Handler ):
  ...
  # The starting and current file path:
  file_name = File
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but here is an example:

```
#other traits imports
from pyface.api import FileDialog
class Something(HasTraits):
    txt_file_name = File
    openTxt = Button('Open...')
    traits_view = View( 
        VGroup( 
            HGroup(
              Item( 'openTxt', show_label = False ),
              '_',
              Item( 'txt_file_name', style = 'readonly', width = 200 ),
            ),
        )
        )
    def _openTxt_fired(self):
        """ Handles the user clicking the 'Open...' button.
        """
        extns = ['*.txt',]#seems to handle only one extension...
        wildcard='|'.join(extns)

        dialog = FileDialog(title='Select text file',
            action='open', wildcard=wildcard,
             default_path = self.txt_file_name)
        if dialog.open() == OK:
            self.txt_file_name = dialog.path
            self.openTxtFile(dialog.path)     
    def openTxtFile(self, path):
        'do something'
        print path
```